# How can I use a PUT request, using Ajax, to change the value of a variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core, and, on my Index View, I want to change the value of a variable when I click a button. I have a class that has a proprety named "Estado". On my Index I have a map with different markers, and each marker has an infowindow that have three buttons ("Aceitar", "Recusar", "Concluido"). When I click in one of those buttons I want to change the value of the variable "Estado" to another value depending on the button that is clicked. Here is the function on my index:

```
 function atualizaBD(id, novoEstado) {
     $.ajax
        ({
            url: '/api/IgnicoesAPI',
            type: 'PUT',
            datatyoe: JSON.stringify({
                id: +id,
                novoEstado: +novoEstado
            }),
            success: function (result) {

                     //What do I do here
                })
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ocorreu um erro!")
            },
        });
}
```

I'm not sure how to use the PUT request. Here is the PUT request on my controller:

```
//// PUT: api/IgnicoesAPI/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutIgnicoes([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Ignicoes ignicoes)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != ignicoes.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(ignicoes).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!IgnicoesExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix few things. Datatype is type of response you expect to receive. ContentType is for type of data you send. If you want to pass data to your request which requires id from route then you have to pass it to url. If you want to pass data like objects then you need to pass it to data option.
More information in [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Code after fixes:

```
 function atualizaBD(id, novoEstado) {
     $.ajax
        ({
            url: `/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}`,
            type: 'PUT',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                id: +id,
                novoEstado: +novoEstado
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                     //What do I do here
                })
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ocorreu um erro!")
            },
        });
}
```

Comment: kyziur, do you have any idea how to change the value of the variable in the database?

Comment: Do you have any errors while trying to update actual object? You can try to go with  _context.DbSetName.Update(ignicoes) and then same as you have await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

Comment: But I need to update the database in the function "atualizaBD(id, novoEstado)"